# bashのexpectでscpを行う際にファイル名にスペースが入っていると別ファイル扱いされる

Tags: bash, expect

bashのexpectでscpを行う際にファイル名がスペース区切りだと別ファイル扱いされます。

```
fromfile='test@testserver.co.jp:/tmp/hoge¥ hoge¥ hoge.txt'
expect -c "
set timeout 3600
spawn env LANG=C /usr/bin/scp ${fromfile} ${encdir}${ori_file}
expect \"password:\"
send \"${PW}\n\"
expect \"$\"
exit 0
"
```

これは(や)、[や]も同様です。一度エスケープする必要がありますが、上のようにエスケープしておいても別ファイル扱いをしてエラーになります。

どのように対処すればいいかご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Comment: ぱっと見、fromfileに代入する文字列（ファイル名）は`''`と`\`で二重エスケープになっています

Comment: ありがとうございます。具体的にどう記載すべきか教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: fromfileへの代入については、`''`か\かどちらか片方にするのがよいかと。逆に、`${fromfile}`と展開している箇所はクォートしたほうがよいかと。試していませんが`'${fromfile}'`とか。

Comment: シェルコマンドでscp test@testserver.co.jp:'hoge hoge.txt' test.txt としても、hoge とhogeで分割されてしまいます。

Comment: なるほど、試してみたところ確かに`''`の中で\が必要ですね。`${filename}`のクォートだけすればよさそう。

Answer (score 1):

コメントの

> シェルコマンドでscp test@testserver.co.jp:'hoge hoge.txt' test.txt としても、hoge
>   とhogeで分割されてしまいます。

が正しいのであれば、

```
export FROMFILE='test@example.co.jp:"/tmp/hoge hoge hoge.txt"'
export ENCDIR='...'
export ORI_FILE='...'
export PW='...'
expect -c '
  set timeout 3600
  spawn env LANG=C /usr/bin/scp "$env(FROMFILE)" "$env(ENCDIR)$env(ORI_FILE)"
  expect "\[Pp\]assword:"
  send -- "$env(PW)\n"
  expect "$"
  exit 0
'
```

かな？ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858176/how-to-escape-spaces-in-path-during-scp-copy-in-linux にあるように、2重にエスケープ or クォートしないとダメっぽいです。

各種変数を、bash の変数として expect スクリプトに埋め込むのではなく、環境変数として渡さないとクォート処理が難しいと思われます。

*2017-03-14 追記:* 定期的に「誰か評価して」と（晒し）あげられてたので、恥ずかしくないようにちゃんとクォート処理に対する考慮を追加しました。パスワードの先頭が `-` である場合への考慮も追加しました。

Answer (score 0):

代わりにスペース、ファイルのリストを指定するには、`{file1,file2...}`を使用することができます:

```
fromfile='test@testserver.co.jp:\{/tmp/hoge¥,/tmp/hoge.txt,hoge¥,hoge.txt\}'
```

[このリンク](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21691584/2614364)と[このリンク](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)からは、複数のファイルをコピーするために：

```
$ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/\{a,b,c\} .
$ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:~/\{foo.txt,bar.txt\} .
```